# Adding nodes group by group to a D3 force directed graph

Tags: graph, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to implement a force directed network similar to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/4062045). However, each of my nodes are assigned a group value for example

```
Node    Group
node1   1
node2   1
node3   2
node4   3
node5   3
```

And I would like the network to grow i.e. after a period of time (say 2 seconds), the subsequent node group is added with their links.

Is this attainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. the trick is to encapsulate the part that draws the graph in a function. Add the specific groups after the approppriate intervals to the `graph` data structure and call that function. The code would look roughly like this.

```
function update(graph) {
    var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
         .data(graph.links)
         .enter().append("line");

    var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
         .data(graph.nodes)
         .enter().append("circle")
         .call(force.drag);

    node.append("title")
         .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    force.start();
}
```

You should be able to reuse everything else basically as it is.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need. I found a perfect implementation of what you just mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400241/updating-links-on-a-force-directed-graph-from-dynamic-json-data?rq=1)