# D3 Force Directed Graph ajax update

Tags: ajax, json, d3.js, force-layout

I am using d3.js and jquery with a PHP back-end (based on yii framework) to create a dynamic force directed  graph to represent the current state of hosts and services on the network that we are monitoring using Nagios.

The graph shows root -> hostgroups -> hosts -> services.  I have created a server side function to return a JSON object in the following format

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "MaaS",
            "object_id": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Convergence",
            "object_id": "531",
            "colour": "#999900"
        },
        {
            "name": "maas-servers",
            "object_id": "719",
            "colour": "#999900"
        },
        {
            "name": "hrg-cube",
            "object_id": "400",
            "colour": "#660033"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": "531"
        },
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": "719"
        },
        {
            "source": "719",
            "target": "400"
        }
    ]
}
```

The nodes contain an object id which is used in the links and colour for displaying the state of the node (OK = green, WARNING = yellow, etc)  The links has the source object ids and target object ids for the nodes.  The nodes and links may change as new hosts are added or removed from the monitoring system

I have the following code which setups the initial SVG and then every 10 seconds

1. Retrieves the current JSON object
2. Creates map of the links
3. Selects the current nodes and links and binds them to the JSON data
4. Entering links are added and exiting links are removed
5. updated and added nodes will change their fill colour and have
   a tooltip with their name added
6. Force is started

   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
       width = 960,
       height = 500;
       node = [];
       link = [];
       force = d3.layout.force()
           .charge(-1000)
           .linkDistance(1)
           .size([width, height]);

   ```
   svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height)
     .append("g");

   setInterval(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "<?php echo $url;?>",
           type: "post",
           async: false,
           datatype: "json",
           success: function(json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) 
           {
               json = $.parseJSON(json);

               var nodeMap = {};
               json.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.object_id] = x; });
               json.links = json.links.map(function(x) {
                   return {
                       source: nodeMap[x.source],
                       target: nodeMap[x.target],
                   };
               });

               link = svg.selectAll("line")
                   .data(json.links);

               node = svg.selectAll("circle")
                   .data(json.nodes,function(d){return d.object_id})

               link.enter().append("line").attr("stroke-width",1).attr('stroke','#999');
               link.exit().remove();

               node.enter().append("circle").attr("r",5);
               node.exit().remove();

               node.attr("fill",function(d){return d.colour});

               node.append("title")
                 .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

               node.call(force.drag);

               force
                   .nodes(node.data())
                   .links(link.data()) 
                   .start()

               force.on("tick", function() {

                   link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                       .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                       .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                       .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                   node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(5, Math.min(width - 5, d.x));  })
                       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(5, Math.min(height - 5, d.y)); });

               });
           }
       });
   },10000);
   ```

An example of the output can be seen at [Network Visualization](https://picasaweb.google.com/102897394941976373993)

All of the above works correctly with the exception that every time the code loops it causes the visualization to restart and the nodes all bounce about until they settle.  What I need is for any current items to stay as they are but any new nodes and links are added to the visualisation and are clickable and draggable, etc.

If anyone can help I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: That happens because you are actually reloading the data and recalculating the layout everytime. Instead of reloading a new JSON everytime, I think you should find a way to check the changes server-side and find a way to connect them with what you have on update. For instance, create a JSON with just the _new_ nodes and links and push those objects into the `.nodes` and `.links` when you call the `force.on("tick", function())`

Comment: I was really hoping for a way to avoid having to deal with passing the current visualization objects back to the server as it makes the whole solution much more complex.  The reason I began looking at d3.js was that you pass d3 the data and it works out what has entered and exited the data saving you from having to do this manually.  Is there no alternative methods?

Comment: Actually, I was re-reading your comment and d3.js **does not** _work out what entered and exited_ in the data. It computes whatever you tell it to with the data you provide. If you want to change the data being used, you have to change it yourself. :)

Comment: Aaaand I messed up in the last comment... Sorry! You should have a read about this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/q8yz2OUMW8g  follow the links as they have precious informatioin on them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to the problem using a mixture of all the advice above, below is the code I have used

```
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();

    var outer = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("pointer-events", "all");

    var vis = outer
        .append('svg:g')
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", rescale))
            .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
        .append('svg:g')

        vis.append('svg:rect')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .attr('fill', 'white');

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .size([width, height])
            .nodes([]) // initialize with a single node
            .linkDistance(1)
            .charge(-500)
            .on("tick", tick);

        nodes = force.nodes(),
            links = force.links();

        var node = vis.selectAll(".node"),
            link = vis.selectAll(".link");

       redraw();

       setInterval(function(){
           $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $url;?>",
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) 
                {
                    var current_nodes = [];
                    var delete_nodes = [];
                    var json = $.parseJSON(json);

                    $.each(json.nodes, function (i,data){

                        result = $.grep(nodes, function(e){ return e.object_id == data.object_id; });
                        if (!result.length)
                        {
                            nodes.push(data);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pos = nodes.map(function(e) { return e.object_id; }).indexOf(data.object_id);
                            nodes[pos].colour = data.colour;
                        }
                        current_nodes.push(data.object_id);             
                    });

                    $.each(nodes,function(i,data){
                        if(current_nodes.indexOf(data.object_id) == -1)
                        {
                            delete_nodes.push(data.index);
                        }       
                    });
                    $.each(delete_nodes,function(i,data){
                        nodes.splice(data,1); 
                    });

                    var nodeMap = {};
                    nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.object_id] = x; });
                    links = json.links.map(function(x) {
                        return {
                            source: nodeMap[x.source],
                            target: nodeMap[x.target],
                            colour: x.colour,
                        };
                    });
                    redraw();
                }
            });
       },2000);


       function redraw()
       {
           node = node.data(nodes,function(d){ return d.object_id;});
           node.enter().insert("circle")
                .attr("r", 5)
           node.attr("fill", function(d){return d.colour})
           node.exit().remove();

           link = link.data(links);
           link.enter().append("line")
               .attr("stroke-width",1)
           link.attr('stroke',function(d){return d.colour});
           link.exit().remove();
           force.start();

       }

       function tick() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return Math.round(d.source.x); })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return Math.round(d.source.y); })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return Math.round(d.target.x); })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return Math.round(d.target.y); });

          node.attr("cx", function(d) { return Math.round(d.x); })
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return Math.round(d.y); });
        }

       function rescale() {
            trans=d3.event.translate;
            scale=d3.event.scale;

            vis.attr("transform",
                "translate(" + trans + ")"
                + " scale(" + scale + ")"); 
        }
```

Comment: I also added a boolean variable that only runs force.start() when an new node is added or deleted to prevent the unneccessary settling on every tick of the graph

Comment: hi! some years later: may you please explain me how i can feed in a json file from my disk in you code above? thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this answer. You need a unique identifier for your nodes, which it appears you have.

[Updating links on a force directed graph from dynamic json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400241/updating-links-on-a-force-directed-graph-from-dynamic-json-data)

Comment: The example is better than what I have currently but when I use this code and attach my ajax call the animation doesn't restart from scratch but it does still move around on update even if the nodes or links haven't changed. This isn't acceptable for what I require as I need the diagram not to move when settled unless there is some change in the data as the diagram will be used as a overall status view and will be on wall boards and movement will draw attention to the screen so should only occur when there is a change.

Answer (score 2):

I recently tried to do the same thing, here is the solution I came up with. What I do is load a first batch of data with `links.php` and then update them with `newlinks.php`, both return a JSON with a list of objects with attributes `sender` and `receiver`. In this example newlinks returns a new sender each time and I set the receiver to be a randomly selected old node.

```
$.post("links.php", function(data) {
// Functions as an "initializer", loads the first data
// Then newlinks.php will add more data to this first batch (see below)
var w = 1400,
    h = 1400;

var svg = d3.select("#networkviz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

var links = [];
var nodes = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
                     .nodes(nodes)
                     .links(links)
                     .size([w, h])
                     .linkDistance(50)
                     .charge(-50)
                     .on("tick", tick);

svg.append("g").attr("class", "links");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");

var linkSVG = svg.select(".links").selectAll(".link"),
    nodeSVG = svg.select(".nodes").selectAll(".node");

handleData(data);
update();

// This is the server call
var interval = 5; // set the frequency of server calls (in seconds)
setInterval(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var beforeDate = new Date(currentDate.setSeconds(currentDate.getSeconds()-interval));
    $.post("newlinks.php", {begin: beforeDate, end: new Date()}, function(newlinks) {
        // newlinks.php returns a JSON file with my new transactions (the one that happened between now and 5 seconds ago)
        if (newlinks.length != 0) { // If nothing happened, then I don't need to do anything, the graph will stay as it was
            // here I decide to add any new node and never remove any of the old ones
            // so eventually my graph will grow extra large, but that's up to you to decide what you want to do with your nodes
            newlinks = JSON.parse(newlinks);
            // Adds a node to a randomly selected node (completely useless, but a good example)
            var r = getRandomInt(0, nodes.length-1);
            newlinks[0].receiver = nodes[r].id;
            handleData(newlinks);
            update();
        }
    });
}, interval*1000);

function update() {
    // enter, update and exit
    force.start();

    linkSVG = linkSVG.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id+"-"+d.target.id; });
    linkSVG.enter().append("line").attr("class", "link").attr("stroke", "#ccc").attr("stroke-width", 2);
    linkSVG.exit().remove();

    var r = d3.scale.sqrt().domain(d3.extent(force.nodes(), function(d) {return d.weight; })).range([5, 20]);
    var c = d3.scale.sqrt().domain(d3.extent(force.nodes(), function(d) {return d.weight; })).range([0, 270]);

    nodeSVG = nodeSVG.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id; });
    nodeSVG.enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("class", "node")
    // Color of the nodes depends on their weight
    nodeSVG.attr("r", function(d) { return r(d.weight); })
           .attr("fill", function(d) {
               return "hsl("+c(d.weight)+", 83%, 60%)";
           });
    nodeSVG.exit().remove();    
}

function handleData(data) {
    // This is where you create nodes and links from the data you receive
    // In my implementation I have a list of transactions with a sender and a receiver that I use as id
    // You'll have to customize that part depending on your data
    for (var i = 0, c = data.length; i<c; i++) {
        var sender = {id: data[i].sender};
        var receiver = {id: data[i].receiver};
        sender = addNode(sender);
        receiver = addNode(receiver);
        addLink({source: sender, target: receiver});
    }
}

// Checks whether node already exists in nodes or not
function addNode(node) {
    var i = nodes.map(function(d) { return d.id; }).indexOf(node.id);
    if (i == -1) {
        nodes.push(node);
        return node;
    } else {
        return nodes[i];
    }
}

// Checks whether link already exists in links or not
function addLink(link) {
    if (links.map(function(d) { return d.source.id+"-"+d.target.id; }).indexOf(link.source.id+"-"+link.target.id) == -1
        && links.map(function(d) { return d.target.id+"-"+d.source.id; }).indexOf(link.source.id+"-"+link.target.id) == -1)
        links.push(link);
}

function tick() {
    linkSVG.attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x;})
            .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y;})
            .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x;})
            .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y;});
    nodeSVG.attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
            .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y});
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
}, "json");
```

This is a very specific implementation so you should fill the holes where necessary depending on your server output. But I believe the D3 backbone is correct and what you are looking for :)
Here is a JSFiddle to toy with it : http://jsfiddle.net/bTyh5/2/

[This code](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) was really useful and inspired some of the parts introduced here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to pass anything back to the server, as long as, *server-side*, you are able to tell what new `nodes` and `links` are being generated. Then, instead of reloading your whole d3 script, you load it once, and in the `force.on("tick", function())`, you make your 10 sec timeout AJAX call to go get from the server the new `data` you want to append, be it `nodes` or `links`.

For instance, imagine that you initially have this JSON in your server:

```
[
    {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "name": "MaaS",
                "object_id": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Convergence",
                "object_id": "531",
                "colour": "#999900"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "links": [
            {
                "source": 0,
                "target": "531"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You go get it from your server with AJAX and parse it with `json = $.parseJSON(json);`.

Then, write your `timeout` so that instead of running the whole function you have in `success`, only runs *after* calculating the layout. Then, again, on `success`, parse the new JSON you got from the server and add the_new_ `nodes` and `links` to the already existing `force.nodes` and `force.links` respectively.

Please note that I didn't test this and I'm not sure how it will work and/or perform, but I think the general approach is feasible.

Comment: That sort of makes sense.  Do you have any examples of how I can compare the current nodes and the nodes in the JSON to find out the differences between the two sets of nodes/links?

Comment: Not really, sorry. But instead of comparing the new/old, can't you just output the new data to a file? Do you just need to add data or do you need to remove data as well? That make the problem a little more complex...

Comment: Data needs to be added and removed and to make matters even more complex the current nodes may have different attributes so may need rerendered

Comment: Well, that makes the problem much more complex... I don't think that I alone can help you with this, although I am very interested in the answers. Lets wait a few more days to see if anyone can help out. Also, keep an eye out for other comments that might show up. I'll promote the question as much as I can. If there are any details you consider important to rephrase the question, be sure to edit the question and add them. Good luck!